# I want to read values from List<long> using Ajax and assign to different HTML element

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to read the value from `List<long>`. I have static method which I call in action result method. That method is called by ajax call. I am returning multiple integer values which I want to show in different HTML elements. Here is my code:

```
public static List<long> GetCounter()
{
    try
    {
        var listofcounters = new List<long>();
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var usercount = db.User.Select(x => x).Count();
            var usercountpending = db.User.Count(x => x.IsApproved == false);
            var visitercounts = db.SiteViewers.Count();
            var todayvisitscount = db.SiteViewers.Count(x => x.VistedDate == DateTime.Now);
            listofcounters.Add(usercount);
            listofcounters.Add(usercountpending);
            listofcounters.Add(visitercounts);
            listofcounters.Add(todayvisitscount);
            return listofcounters;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CounterValues()
{
    try
    {
        var listofcounters = SuperUserManager.GetCounter();
        return Json(listofcounters, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

my AJAX call

```
function UpdateDashboard() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../Admin/AdminHome/CounterValues',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#labeluser').text(usercount);
            $('#labelpendinguser').text(pendinguser);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is going to return an array like `[234,456,768]`. Now you do no't know which item in the array is UserCount (*well, you know if you look at the server code and find the order. But it is not clearly readable code!*)

I suggest you create a simple POCO to represent the data you want to send

```
public class DashboardVm
{
   public long UserCount { set;get;}
   public long PendingUserCount { set;get;}
   public long VisiterCount  { set;get;}
}
```

Have your `GetCounter` method returns an instance of this instead of the list of long.

```
public DashboardVm GetCounter()
{
    var vm=new DashboardVm();
    try
    {
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            vm.UserCount = db.User.Select(x => x).Count();
            vm.PendingUserCount = db.User.Count(x => x.IsApproved == false);
            // TO DO : Set other property values as well              
        }
        return vm;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // to do : Log the error so you know what went wrong
        throw;
    }
}
```

and return the result of this method call instead of the array.

```
public ActionResult CounterValues()
{
  var vm=GetCounter();
  return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now in your ajax method's success callback, you can access it like

```
success : function(data){
    $('#labeluser').text(data.UserCount);
    $('#labelpendinguser').text(data.PendingUserCount);
}
```